# Detach every record of model in pivot table when deleting model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

Imagine I have `User` and `Role` models. Now what I am doing is deleting several users from database. For example I delete users with IDs 1, 2, 3 and 4. Now I want to delete everything from pivot table where user_id = 1, 2, 3 or 4. What is the best way to do that? I mean laravel implementation.

Comment: Sorry I cannot imagine it. There is no such thing as a pivot table in sql just tables with rows and columns. Please add sample data as text to the question to illustrate your question.

Comment: pivot table is `user_role` table with user_id and role_id. many to many relationship.

Comment: Can you show how you're deleting the users?

Comment: You could use foreign keys with ON DELETE=CASCADE in your table

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into the deleting event on a user model to also delete their role.

User.php

```
Class User extends Model {

    protected static function boot() {
        static::deleting(function($model) {
             // Whenever we delete a user delete their roles first.
             $model->roles()->sync([]);
        });

    }

    function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('roles');
    }
}
```

You can also use model events and observers to do this which might be a bit cleaner: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events.  The issue with observers and the pattern above is that whenever you batch delete you will have an `n + 1` problem.

If you want to batch delete users the most efficient way to do it would be to just delete data from the pivot table manually, Something like this:

```
function deleteUsers($userIds) {
    // Delete the users roles
    DB::('user_roles')
        ->whereIn('user_id', $userIds)
        ->delete();

    // Delete the users
    User::whereIn('id', $userIds)
        ->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if users and roles have many to many relationships then just work as below for your problem

Here is the sample codes
User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements CanResetPassword
{
  protected $table = "users";

 public function roles(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user');
 }
}
```

Role.php

```
class Role extends Model{
  protected $table = "roles";

 public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'role_user');
 }
}
```

From your controller, you can do this

```
class AnyTestController extends Controller{
  public function test(){
   //Suppose your user id is 1 then delete user from pivot table 
   $user = User::find(1);
   $user->roles()->detach();
   $user->delete();
   }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't have `$user`, I have `$users`.

Comment: $users = User::find([1,2,3,4]);
$users->each(function($user){
 $user->roles()->detach();
 $user->delete();
});

Answer (score 1):

Add this cole in models to before delete user or role clear registers in pivot table.

User.php

```
protected static function boot ()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting (function ($user) {
        $user->roles()->detach();
    });
}
```

Role.php

```
protected static function boot ()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting (function ($role) {
        $role->users()->detach();
    });
}
```